# Dagger : Object is bound multiple times:

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger

Component C uses 2 different modules which have 1 similar dependency. Facing this compilation error:

'String is bound multiple times'

```
class ModuleA{
    @Provides
    fun provideString() = ""
    /*
    other providers
     */
}

class ModuleB{
    @Provides
    fun provideString() = ""
    /*
    other providers
     */
}

@Component(modules = [A::class, B::class])
interface ComponentC{
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun context(context: Context): Builder

        fun moduleA(module: A): Builder

        fun moduleB(module: B): Builder

        fun build(): ComponentC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dagger (and you :) cannot distinguish between string from `ModuleA` and string from `ModuleB`. So you have to use some qualifiers. You can create your own([short tutorial](https://medium.com/mindorks/qualifiers-in-dagger-android-development-c0574cca87a2)) or use `@Named` annotation like this:

```
class ModuleA{
    @Provides
    @Named("stringA")
    fun provideString() = ""
    /*
    other providers
     */
}

class ModuleB{
    @Provides
    @Named("stringB")
    fun provideString() = ""
    /*
    other providers
     */
}
```

Please note, that you have to use same qualifier in the injection site